# Gradle compilation corrupts compressed file

Tags: java, zip, compression

I'm building a Minecraft server plugin jar file with Gradle. Any zip files from `resources` will be corrupt after compilation, but are openable through intellij IDE, but compiled they are completely corrupt.

Winrar's error: [image]

I'm trying to save it then open it and the error I get is:

```
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1469)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1477)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1315)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1277)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:709)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:243)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:172)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:186)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at net.advancedplugins.mpets.impl.utils.ASManager.unZip(ASManager.java:830)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at net.advancedplugins.mpets.impl.customMobs.utils.PetsConverter.convertFromMPet(PetsConverter.java:22)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at net.advancedplugins.mpets.impl.customMobs.CustomEntityHandler.readMobs(CustomEntityHandler.java:113)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at net.advancedplugins.mpets.impl.customMobs.CustomEntityHandler.<init>(CustomEntityHandler.java:71)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at com.kirelcodes.miniaturepets.MiniaturePets.onEnable(MiniaturePets.java:137)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:264)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:342)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:480)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_19_R2.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:539)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_19_R2.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:453)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_19_R2.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:938)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:802)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:27)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:149)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_19_R2.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:847)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_19_R2.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:832)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.bg(DedicatedServer.java:413)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.b(DedicatedServer.java:389)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:1201)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:1017)
[14:14:00] [Server thread/WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:301)
```

I tried opening the .zip files within .jar and open generated ones, they are corrupt. Any other files which arent compressed are completely fine.

Comment: There is a definite possibility that something in your `build.gradle` is causing this. We could probably tell you more if you shared its contents with us.

Comment: @teapot418 yes it was! In processResources I had `filteringCharset 'UTF-8'` which caused it! Thank you